# Accounts.onLogin with IronRouter

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I'm trying to redirect user to a page after login.
Trying to use Router.go from Accounts.onLogin callback:

```
Accounts.onLogin () ->
  Router.go('users.new')
```

When I try this on the server I get `TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'go'`

On the client I get `Accounts.onLogin undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you've got a problem here :

`Accounts.onLogin` is undefined on the client because it is a server-only API.

**UPDATE 15/06/2015 :** this is no longer true, `Accounts.onLogin` is now available on the client too.

Router.go is undefined on the server because redirecting with iron:router is a client-only API.

If you are using `{{> loginButtons}}` you can try this workaround on the client :

```
Tracker.autorun(function(){
  if(Meteor.user()){
    // login handler
    Router.go("users.new");
  }
  else{
    // logout handler
  }
});
```

If you are using a custom login form with `Meteor.loginWithSomething`, you can perform the redirection in the success callback of the login method.

Comment: Worked with Deps.autorun. Not sure what is Tracker.autorun. Maybe cause i'm on meteor 0.8 it's slightly different API.

Comment: Yes, this has been backward compatibly renamed in 0.9.1

Comment: Account.onlogin is not a server only thing - it's an everywhere thing - has this something that has been changed since this answer?

Comment: `Accounts.onLogin` is now available on the client according to this commit : https://github.com/meteor/meteor/commit/b5861c114ab2b8f76c36d9e4ed2ada84903732e4